Calculate the number of points in a given radius by X and Y coordinates
I have a python code where, when given a list of points (X and Y coordinate pairs) in a dataframe and a specified circle radius I would like the code to go through each point, treat it as the the center of the circle, and find how many other points are inside the circle selection.
Looking around Ive seen people suggest a similar problem using longitudes and latitudes can be solved with BallTree from SciKit-Learn so I've tried that but I'm not getting the answers I'm expecting. My code is below:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcde'),'X': [10, 1000, 1010, 5000, 5100],'Y': [10, 1000, 1010, 5000, 5100]})

radius = int(input('Enter the selection radius of the circle:'))

coords = df[["X","Y"]]

tree = BallTree(coords, metric='haversine')
answers = tree.query_radius(coords, r=radius, count_only=True)

print(answers)

For example when i do radius = 100 i get an answer of [1 1 1 1 1] which is not correct. Any ideas how to get this to work in the simplest way in python?

The issue you're encountering is because the BallTree is being used with the haversine metric, which is designed for computing distances on a spherical surface, typically used with longitude and latitude coordinates. However, in your case, you're working with Cartesian coordinates (X, Y), where the Euclidean distance should be used instead.
You should replace this line:
tree = BallTree(coords, metric='haversine')

With:
tree = BallTree(coords, metric='euclidean')


Hello. Thank you for the insight into the metrics in BallTree and which should be used when. However It seems that even when i change metric='euclidean' i am still getting the incorrect answer of [1 1 1 1 1]. Is there some other aspect of BallTree I am not understanding?

Well something is wrong with your setup, try the code in google colab.
For me, trying your code in colab returns: [5 5 5 5 5] (haversine and radius=100)
But when using euclidean and radius=100: it returns [1 2 2 1 1]

For random coordinates as you have given you should use euclidean geometry
tree = BallTree(coords, metric='euclidean')

Haversine need specific radian coordinates to be put in. These values you have used as test don’t make sense in this context.
After looking it up: haversine can be calculated by dividing the latitude (-90 up to 90) and/or longitude (-180 up to 180) value multiplied by pi / 180. This means it cannot be larger than about 1.5 and 3.14
